# This only seems to work in Clion, when i run it in Visual Studio the World Array and commented out use of Chunk in the main thread dont work

Tags: c++

This all works in CLion hover not in VS

For the World Array class it gives an Exception thrown at 0x00007FF713162AD0 in MineCraftClone.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000BFA. on line 83.

And when the alternate use of the classes i made using Chunk not World it throws the same error after the code has ran, perhaps this error is to do with destructors

```
#include<D:\glfw-3.3.8\glfw-3.3.8\include\GLFW\glfw3.h>
#include<D:\glm-master\glm\glm.hpp>
#include<D:\FastNoiseLite-master\Cpp\FastNoiseLite.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>


const int xMax = 32;
const int yMax = 384;
const int zMax = 32;

enum BlockType
{
    Stone = 0,
    Air = 1,
    Water = 2,
    Dirt = 3,
    Grass = 4
};

BlockType getBlock(int x, int y, int z)
{
    double frequency = 0.2;
    double amplitude = 10;

    double xOffset = sin(x * (frequency)) * (amplitude - 5) + sin(x * (frequency - 0.1)) * (amplitude + 5) + sin(x * (frequency + 0.1)) * amplitude;
    double zOffset = sin(z * (frequency)) * (amplitude - 4) + sin(z * (frequency - 0.06)) * (amplitude + 5) + sin(z * (frequency + 0.05)) * amplitude  + 2;

    double surfaceY = 100 + xOffset + zOffset;


    /*FastNoiseLite noise;
    noise.SetNoiseType(noise.NoiseType_Perlin);
    noise.SetFractalOctaves(4);

    double surfaceY = 100 + noise.GetNoise(float(x), float(z)) * 20 + noise.GetNoise(float(x*0.2), float(z*0.35)) * 10;*/

    double waterLevel = 125;
    return (y < surfaceY) ? Stone :(y < waterLevel) ? Water : Air;
}

class Array3D
{
    int*** data;
    int numberOfRows;
    int numberOfColumns;
    int numberOfAisles;

public:
    Array3D(int rows, int columns, int aisles) : numberOfRows(rows), numberOfColumns(columns), numberOfAisles(aisles)
    {
        data = new int** [rows];
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            data[i] = new int* [columns];
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
            {
                data[i][j] = new int[aisles];
            }
        }
    }

    ~Array3D()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < numberOfColumns; j++)
            {
                delete[] data[i][j];
            }
            delete[] data[i];
        }
        delete[] data;
    }

    void Set(int row, int column, int aisle, int value)
    {
        data[row][column][aisle] = value;
    }

    int Get(int row, int column, int aisle)
    {
        return data[row][column][aisle];
    }
};

class Chunk
{
    Array3D data;
    int cornerBlockX;
    int cornerBlockZ;

public:
    Chunk() : cornerBlockX(0), cornerBlockZ(0), data(xMax, yMax, zMax){}

    Chunk(int cornerBlockX, int cornerBlockZ) : cornerBlockX(cornerBlockX), cornerBlockZ(cornerBlockZ), data(xMax, yMax, zMax)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < xMax; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < yMax; j++)
                for (int k = 0; k < zMax; k++)
                {
                    BlockType block = getBlock(cornerBlockX + i, j, cornerBlockZ + k);
                    data.Set(i, j, k, block);
                }
    }

    int Get(int row, int column, int aisle)
    {
        return data.Get(row, column, aisle);
    }
};

class World
{
    Chunk** data;
    int numberOfRows;
    int numberOfColumns;

public:
    World(int rows, int columns) : numberOfRows(rows), numberOfColumns(columns), data(new Chunk* [rows])
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            data[i] = new Chunk[columns];
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
            {
                data[i][j] = Chunk(i * xMax, j * zMax);
            }
        }
    }

    ~World()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++)
        {
            delete[] data[i];
        }
        delete[] data;
    }

    Chunk GetChunk(int row, int column)
    {
        return data[row][column];
    }
};

void PrintChunk2D(Chunk array, int zSlice)
{
    int lines = 0;

    for (int i = yMax - 1; i > -1; i--)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < xMax; j++)
        {
            if (array.Get(j, i, zSlice) == 0) std::cout << '#';
            else if (array.Get(j, i, zSlice) == 2) std::cout << '~';
            else if (array.Get(j, i, zSlice) == 1) std::cout << ' ';
            else std::cout << '@';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
        lines++;
    }

    std::cout << lines;
}

int main()
{
    int chunkX = 0;
    int chunkZ = 0;
    int cornerBlockX = xMax * chunkX;
    int cornerBlockZ = zMax * chunkZ;

    //Error ? in VS only!? Destructor?

    int worldSize[2] = { 2, 2 };
    World world(worldSize[0], worldSize[1]);
    PrintChunk2D(world.GetChunk(chunkX, chunkZ), 0);


    //Chunk chunk(cornerBlockX, cornerBlockZ);
    //PrintChunk2D(chunk, 0);

}
```

This in CLion generates a procedually generated world based on a few sine waves and then creates an 3d array or chunk of integers that i display as 0 = #, 1 = ' ' and 2 = ~. I use these characters to display a slice of the chunk

Comment: C++ doesn't really work like that. Sure, there could be a compiler bug, but those are stupidly rare. Odds are really good that it doesn't work in either tool, you're just not seeing the failure as easily in CLion. Visual Studio has a fabulous debugger that you can use to step through the program and see exacly what goes wrong when the program crashes. From there you can backtrack to see how the program got into trouble.

Comment: Two different compilers (assuming you use MinGW with CLion) giving two different results, that suggests *undefined behavior* in your code.

Comment: @user4581301 I wondered if that was the case especially considering that, there was some sort of destructor issue in Visual Studio

Comment: My ***guess*** is that it depends on you breaking [the rules of three, five and zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). As a possible solution, use the rule of zero and change all your own dynamic memory allocation and all your pointers to using `std::vector`. And use the vectors `at` function for element access.

Comment: If your Visual Studio is up to date, you can [turn on sanitizers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/sanitizers/asan?view=msvc-170) to help you find the mistake. You may also be able to use sanitizers in whatever compiler CLion's sitting on top of, but Sanitizer support on Windows is still dodgy.

Comment: Another thing, use strong enumerations and create arrays of the `BlockType` type instead. That could catch some problems if you try to use invalid values for block types. And build with (*lots* of) extra warnings enabled.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it was the rules of 3 5 and zero thanks. I only started learning c++ after a bit of c# a few days ago so i had no idea about this.

Comment: Also important early reading: [What is meant by Resource Acquisition is Initialization (RAII)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2321511/4581301)

Answer (score 0):

I think it was the rule of three, five or zero. However im not sure, but changing the pointers to vectors worked so it probably was one of them

It was probably to do with lines like: in the World Class
data[i][j] = Chunk(i * xMax, j * zMax)
or
data[i] = new Chunk[columns])

Comment: [Here's a little trick that you can extend to 3 dimensions if you really need them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2076668/4581301).